# Android studio does not start; Tries to download Android SDK tools rev 24.1.2 and fails

Tags: android, android-studio

I have Downloaded and installed the recommended android studio bundle from developer android website. It installed ok. When I try to run it, Android studio setup wizard appears and tries to download Android SDK tools rev 24.1.2 and other archives
[image: Android studio setup wizard download screen]

but it is unable to download any thing, as you can see in the screen. It gives a "Download Interrupted: Unexpected HTTP Status 408". I am using a good internet. Not too slow. It is a 3G mobile internet.

Comment: I had the same issue once. Probably the connection was lost at a point of time while downloading and the size of the sdk components are big so it requires a constant connection try with a faster and constant internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like just a network issue. Make sure that you have an active and stable Internet connection. Btw, i see that you're downloading a system image. Just don't do this. You don't need any slow emulator, they're useless. Try genymotion or just physical device for test.

Answer (score -1):

I found Answer, Just Disconnect your Internet and Restart SDK. It say you for Internet Connection but you canceled it and click next, it's Run